# g++ error with the Docker airflow install using astronomer image

Tags: python-3.x, docker, dockerfile, airflow

**Description:**
I have PyICU error during building airflow image from (initial.Dockerfile) and build didn’t complete because PYICU error, then modified to add some libraries like (python-dev libc-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev zlib1g-dev g++ pkg-config ) but its not helping me still getting error because of g++. all help is appreciated

initial.Dockerfile - This is the initial docker (https://github.com/rv1448/airflow-install/blob/b245329af4f3c863778126577d32bd095b004e4b/initial.Dockerfile)

Modified Dockerfile - This is handle PYICU but still getting the g++ error (https://github.com/rv1448/airflow-install/blob/b245329af4f3c863778126577d32bd095b004e4b/Dockerfile)

Link to the repo - (https://github.com/rv1448/airflow-install.git)

Answer (score 0):

You might try to use the technique of "customizing" the official Airflow image from the community rather than using the Astronomer one. The Official Airflow Image has more features (described in "customizing" image section here: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/docker-stack/build.html#customizing-the-image where you can also find a few examples of customizing the image, where you need to install dependencies that need "build-essentials" to be installed. Maybe that will help you.

If you need more understanding on what it does, you can watch my talk: https://youtu.be/wDr3Y7q2XoI from the last year's Airflow Summit, where I describe the ins- and outs- of the official image.